# Download macOS Installer.dmg file

Tags: dmg, macos

Apple yesterday released macOS Sierra for public. The update weighs ~5 GB. I have two Macs with me: one is my personal, the other my office has given. Instead of downloading the installer twice (10 GB), It would be great to download the copy and once use it to upgrade multiple devices (iMacs/Mac minis).

I have tried to find the dmg file but I haven't been able to find it, instead I was redirected to the App Store. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I downloaded it once and pointed all of my macs to download it from a local server using the method outlined here: https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/macos-sierra-direct-download.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Download on the first machine.
- When complete, the Installer will auto-launch.
- Quit it.

The Installer is in /Applications/ and has the name *Install macOS Sierra*. [BTW it's not a .dmg, but an .app file]

Copy it to a safe place; after install it will be auto-deleted from Applications.

The copy can then be used on any other machine. Drop into the Applications folder on that machine & launch.

Comment: Or, instead of a 'safe place', just straight into the /Applications folder of whatever machines you're upgrading.

Comment: Unless, like me, you keep them. You need one copy that's not in Applications, as they get deleted after update.

Comment: It's an installer DMG too.  Just right-click the "Applications/Install MacOS Sierra" app, and select "Open Package Contents".  Then go into the SharedSupport and you'll see the ~4.9 GB DMG file.  COPY it to another location (drag-n-drop will not work, it just creates a shortcut).

Comment: It contains a .dmg, sure - but that's not necessarily the best practise, to remove it from the app, as it then won't work as a simple updater.